# my code can run well, but when I check it with valgrind,there is a error " is 0 bytes after a "

Tags: valgrind

here is my code （ Mask_makeMask function） :

```
    unsigned char *Mask_makeMask(int width, unsigned char *frame, 
    int *mask, HXecLevel level,int version,int autoMask)
    {
    unsigned char *masked;
    unsigned char *tempmask;

    int temp;
    int maskv[4];
    int maskval = *mask; 


    if(autoMask == 1)
    {
        tempmask = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * width);
        if(tempmask == NULL) return NULL;

        //>>>>>mask 00 process Mask_evaluate is to generate the marsk
        maskv[0] = Mask_evaluate(width,frame);

        //mask 01
        maskMakers[0](width, frame, tempmask);
        maskv[1] = Mask_evaluate(width,tempmask);


        //mask 02
        memset(tempmask,0,sizeof(tempmask));
        maskMakers[1](width, frame, tempmask);
        maskv[2]= Mask_evaluate(width,tempmask);

        //mask 03
        memset(tempmask,0,sizeof(tempmask));
        maskMakers[2](width, frame, tempmask);
        maskv[3] = Mask_evaluate(width,tempmask);
        temp = maskv[0];    
        maskval = 0;
        int i;
        for(i= 1 ;i<4;i++)
        {
        if(temp >= maskv[i])
        {
            maskval = i;
            temp = maskv[i];
        }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tempmask = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * width);
        if(tempmask == NULL) return NULL;
        if(maskval ==0)
        Mask_evaluate(width,frame);
        else if( maskval >0 && maskval <=3)
        {
        maskMakers[maskval-1](width, frame, tempmask);
        Mask_evaluate(width,tempmask); 
        }
        free(tempmask);
    }

    >masked = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * width);#line 4319 valgrind  
                                                  shows this is an error

    >if(masked == NULL)
    >{
    >   return NULL;
    >} 

    if(maskval ==0 )
    {
        memcpy(masked,frame,width * width);
    }
    else
        maskMakers[maskval-1](width, frame, masked);


    Mask_writeInformation(width, masked, maskval, level,version);
    *mask = maskval;

    if(autoMask == 1)
        free(tempmask);

    return masked;
    }
```

> -------my code runs well but the valgrind log is blew:

```
    ==2570==  Address 0x5c30429 is 0 bytes after a block of size 729 alloc'd
    ==2570==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
    >==2570==    by 0x410CB07: Mask_makeMask (barhanxin.c:4319)
    ==2570==    by 0x410CF00: HXcode_encodeMask (barhanxin.c:4468)
```

1. I tried to initialize the masked by using memset(masked,0,width * width) 
     when the masked is not null, the  HXcode_encodeMask called the 
     Mask_makeMask function,so I think the issue is Mask_makeMask, could anybody
     give me some advice how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need the other half of that error you posted.  Valgrind is telling you that you either read or wrote off the end of `masked`.  You might have a `<=` in a for loop somewhere else in the code (`Mask_writeInformation`?)  In any case, it'll be in the other half of that error.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that ,I thought it was a independent log ,so I only posted it partially, here is the whole log below:

Comment: Ah... you neglected to paste in the log.